# How to display Total cost of products added in wishlist using yith woocommerce wishlist plugin?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I'm developing E-Commerce website using Wordpress and Woocommerce plugins.
I've installed yith Woocommerce wishlist plugin for user to add product in wishlist, it's display unit product cost, add to cart button and product image.

**I want to display Total product cost added in wishlist** and for that add to cart button also. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

To display Total product cost with YITH Woocommerce Wishlist plugin, you can do this with Jquery :

```
var myArray = $(".wishlist_table .amount"); // Recover all product cost
var result = 0;
for (var i = 0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
    result += parseFloat(myArray[i].childNodes["0"].data); // Make the sum
}

$("#som").text(result); // Place total in a HTML element - my ID is "som" but no matter what it is

$(".remove_from_wishlist").live('click', function(){ // When user remove item with AJAX         
    var href = $(this).attr('href'); // Find parent
    href = href.replace(/\D/g,'');  
    var arrayTo = $('#yith-wcwl-row-'+href+' .amount').text(); 
    arrayTo = parseFloat(arrayTo.replace(/\u20ac/g, '')); // u20ac is unicode character for euro sign but works with just 'D' instead
    var recoverTotal = $("#som").text(); // Recover the total
    var result2 = recoverTotal - arrayTo;
    $("#som").text(result2); // Display the final result
});
```

You have to put this code in a shortcode function. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which wishlist plugin you're using as there are a few wishlist plugins.

However, I have written a solution for this while using [YITH Woocommerce Wishlist plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-wishlist/). Sharing that code here if that helps.

```
function tnc_wishlist_summary_cart(){
    global $woocommerce;
    $wl_items = YITH_WCWL()->get_products();
    $product_price = 0;
    foreach ($wl_items as $key => $item) {

        $the_product = wc_get_product($item['prod_id']);
        $product_price += $the_product->get_price();

        if(isset($_REQUEST['add_all_to_cart'])){
            $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($item['prod_id']);
        }
    }
    $output = 'Total Price: '.$product_price;
    $output .= "<a href='?add_all_to_cart'>Add All to Cart</a>";
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'tnc-wishlist-summary', 'tnc_wishlist_summary_cart' );
```

Put This code in functions.php or inside a standalone plugin and put the following shortcode on the Wishlist page.

```
[tnc-wishlist-summary]
```

It will output Total Price and a link for adding all to cart. Not styled though. You need to style it according to your needs.

Thanks